# How to use while loop with string joinnig with plus?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, t-sql

I would like to read rows from txt files and make some processing in the procedure TESTSP. But I do have some error. How should I rewrite my queries? Best regards.

**Code:**

```
DECLARE @i int
set @i =0
WHILE(@i<85)
begin
@i=@i+1;
if(@i<10)
begin
    exec TESTSP'C:\dosya\X_20130208_0'+@i+'.txt'
end
else
begin
    exec TESTSP 'C:\dosya\X_20130208_'+convert(@i as varchar(2))+'.txt'
end
end
```

**Errors:**

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '@i'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

Comment: The errors are pretty clear on what you need to look at.

Comment: Advices on your code: 1) build your parameter before the execution of the procedure in a local variable; 2) prefix your procedure with the schema name (dbo.) 3) when concatenating strings with integers convert the latter to string; 4) consider SSIS package if you need to do lots of file import and processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `convert or cast @i (int) to varchar` *for* `string concatenation`. Also note the `syntax of Convert` as you have used cast syntax to convert.

```
declare @i int = 0, @path varchar(500)

while(@i<85)
begin

    --You can simplify (or remove if condition) using right() function as below

    --Assign @path here before calling stored procedure
    select @i = @i + 1, 
           @path = 'C:\dosya\X_20130208_' + right(100 + @i, 2) + '.txt'

    --Execute stored procedure here
    exec TESTSP @path

end
```

Comment: select 'C:\dosya\X_20130208_0'+right('0'+convert(varchar(10),@i),2)+'.txt'
 exec MRTG_FILE_COLLECT 'C:\dosya\X_20130208_0'+right('0'+convert(varchar(10),@i),2)+'.txt' problem after EXEC

Comment: exec TESTSP 'C:\dosya\X_20130208_0'+right('0'+convert(varchar(10),@i),2)+'.txt'  problem is that.

Comment: DECLARE @i int;
set @i =0
declare @test nvarchar(2);
select convert( varchar(2),@i)
select 'C:\dosya\X_20130208_0'+right('0'+convert(varchar(10),@i),2)+'.txt'

Comment: You have to be clear about your error or what you are saying. I am not getting it. I have corrected the errors I saw and also simplified your loop. I have no idea about the stuff that you have NOT shown in the question...

Comment: `@i=@i+1;` needs to be `SET @i = @i + 1;` or `SET @i += 1;`. Also I don't think you can build the expression when calling the stored procedure...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks and fixed ...Good point. I think that is okay. This is bit similar to calling an sp within a cursor..

Comment: @Kaf I don't think so. Did you try it? `EXEC sp_spaceused 'foo'+'bar';
` yields `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '+'.`

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I think I got what you meant now. Fixed it by assigning to `@path` and then using it to exec sp. Thanks !

Comment: The `@i+1` in the `@path` expression should be `@i`, otherwise `@i` gets incremented an extra time before being concatenated.

Comment: Also, you could simplify the `right` expression to just `right(100 + @i, 2)`.